# Why does jquery's on() only work once?

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I have a simple script that works only once. My script will check a checkbox if I click anywhere inside a table row. However, if I click inside the row a second, third, etc. time, then it doesn't work anymore. Why? I am now using jquery 1.9.1. My script worked previously when I was using jquery 1.8 with `live()` instead of `on()`.

HTML:

```
<tr class="row">
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click",".row",function(){
        var loc = $(this).find('input');
        var ischecked = loc.attr("checked");
        if(ischecked) {
            loc.attr("checked", false);
        } else {
            loc.attr("checked", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you should be using `loc.prop("checked")`, not `.attr()`.

Comment: Setting "checked" attr to true or false has nothing to do with the checkbox being checked or not. As long as the attribute is there, it is checked.

Comment: You should add and remove the attribute, not set it to true orfalse.

Comment: As @Barmar says, use prop. See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: if(ischecked == "checked"), try with this condition

Comment: @box86rowh - It's much better to use `prop` with checkboxes.  This is [well documented](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace attr with prop as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on("click",".row",function(){
        var loc = $(this).find('input');
        var ischecked = loc.attr("checked");
        if(ischecked) {
            loc.prop("checked", false);
        } else {
            loc.prop("checked", true);
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/uUmPX/)

Answer (score 0):

When the `checked` attribute is there in an `<input />`, never mind about its value, it becomes checked. So replace the following:

```
loc.attr("checked", false);
```

With:

```
loc.prop("checked", false);
```

Or, you can do so in a single line of code this way:

```
loc.prop("checked", !loc.prop("checked"));
```